# validating , adding custome messages to cloned elements

Tags: jquery, validation

Ihave cloned a couple of form fields and trying to add jquery validation(http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js)

I have added the below line (this sample took from one of the previous answers for similar question) but not working.

```
 $("#NameOnCard"+uniqueId).rules("add", { required:true,minlength:3,maxlength:15 });
```

Please see the demo.

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tK4f6/20/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a few mistakes in your code that are causing your issues.  Some of them may just be due to how you copied it to your jsFiddle, but I'll show them all here:

- You need to call `$.validate` once the page is loaded, not in your `click` handler for the submit button.  You don't need a click handler at all, as the plugin will take care of everything for you (and call the `submitHandler` if it is valid)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#iPayForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin   
        //all your options here
    });
});
```

- Your form needs to have the `id` you reference in the `$.validate` call.

You had:

```
<form class="form-horizontal >
```

Should be:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="iPayForm" >
```

- When you are cloning the payment information, you put the adding of rules code inside the click handler of the remove button.  Instead it needs to go inside the click handler of the **add** button.

Should look like this:

```
$('#' + divID).find('input,select').each(function () { 
        $(this).attr('id', ($(this).attr('id')).slice(0,-1) + uniqueId);    
        $(this).attr('name', ($(this).attr('name')).slice(0,-1) + uniqueId);
       $(this).val('');

    });
    $("#NameOnCard"+uniqueId).rules("add", { required:true,minlength:3,maxlength:15 });
```

I've made a "working" demo here:  http://jsfiddle.net/tK4f6/21/

Comment: Thank you verymuch. Actually  iwas able to find a solution from a different thread that posted by you.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my othe rquestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022020/jquery-clone-validation-removing-error-class.