# jquery clone validation removing error class

Tags: jquery, validation

I am cloning a div tag that has set of form fields. I am able to maintain unique ID's and names with below code.

Issue: Before cloning (Clicking add button) If I click submit, validation is executed and put some error messages. If I click add button now (cloning) it is carrying error label tag to new cloned section. Because of this, if I removed data from a required field in first section, error message is displaying in both original section and cloned section.

I think if I can remove label for error from original section while cloning that should solve problem.

```
       $('#' + divID).find('input,select').each(function () {    
        $(this).attr('id', ($(this).attr('id')).slice(0,-1) + uniqueId);    
        $(this).attr('name', ($(this).attr('name')).slice(0,-1) + uniqueId);
       $(this).val('');     

    });
```

I would like to remove the below line within above condition while cloning.

```
   <label class="error" style="display: inline-block;" for="NameOnCard1">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is search for `label.error` elements in the newly cloned container:

```
   container.find('label.error').remove();
```